# Папка как проект CLION

Tags: git, clion

Создал проект с таким же названием, как и у папки; в той же директории. Теперь каждый раз создаётся CMAKE файл и другие папки (соответственно как и у любого проекта CLION). Можно ли как-то отменить изменения/откатиться к предыдущей версии?

Comment: У CLION нет проектов, можно использовать только cmake. Чтобы откатить изменения можно использовать систему контроля версий, например mercurial. В тегах к вопросу уже есть git - так а что вы не откатываетесь, раз уже его используете?

Comment: Попробовал откатиться на предыдущий коммит, но при открытии CLiona папка всё равно открывается, как проект.

Comment: Еще раз - в CLION **нет** проектов. Если при открытии пустой папки там появляются файлы cmake - то видимо вы не открываете папку, а создаете новый cmake проект из исходников. Если просто открыть папку (Open), то ничего создаваться не должно, но и работать с файлами можно будет только как в текстовом редакторе (то бишь без синтаксиса, сборки и отладки).

Comment: Видимо плохо описал проблему. У меня была папка, в которой находились "проекты" (не знаю как иначе назвать) CLion. При создании нового "проекта" указал его расположение, такое же как и у главной папки (с соотвествующим названием). Теперь внутри неё помимо предыдущих проектов каждый раз создаются папки cmake и idea.